# Connecting one drop-down under another drop down in winform in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I am trying to design a ***winform*** using C# where I want to ***connect one drop-down with another drop-down***. When I will create ***an item of 1st drop-down then the second drop-down will appear for that particular option selected***. What might be the code in c# for the same?

Comment: So you'll want an event listener, which essentially is attached to the first drop down. When you select a result, that will then trigger the data to be populated in the second dropdown based on the currently selected value in the first drop down.

Comment: By drop-down do you mean ComboBox? If so did you look into events more particularly SelectedIndexChange Event? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You could data bind to your controls, another option rather than hooking up to events; can be done a few ways, but with out further details and clarification we are not much help. Please update your question to include more details and clarify the actual problem you're having.

Comment: You can use data-binding for this purpose or you can rely on SelectedIndexChanged event. Please share more context of the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

One option, note that this only works properly for visual design purposes in a net framework project. Core has bugs they haven't worked out yet so data binding design is disabled. You can do the design in a netfw project and import it into core afterwards:

- add a new DataSet type of file to your project
- open it and the goth click the surface .. add DataTable
- call it Person, right click it, add column.. add a column for Id, and another for Name. Make Id int type
- Add another table, Address this time, and again columns like Id, Street, PersonId
- Ensure Address's PersonId column is the same datatype as Person.Id
- Right click Person.Id and set it primary key, same for Address Id
- Click on the key icon so the whole line goes blue and then click drag and drop it onto PersonId in Address
- The data relation window appears; ensure person is the primary and address is the child/foreign, ok
- switch to form designer
- Open Data Sources panel (View menu, Other Windows)
- Expand all the nodes. Drag the top level Person node and drop it on the form. Drag the Address node that is a child of Person and drop it on the form. Do not drag the top level Address node to the form
- delete the grid views: we don't want them, we just want the binding sources that they created
- Add two combos to the form. Set their drop down style to DropDownList
- In the first combo set it's DataSource to the personBindingSource, and set the display and value member properties to name/id
- In the second combo set it's DataSource to AddressBindingSource, and set it's display/value members to street/id
- go to code view and add some data to the dataset so there is something to show:

  var p1 = datasetX.Person.AddPersonRow(1, "John"); //assumes you made ID column first and is of int type
  var p2 = datasetX.Person.AddPersonRow(2, "Jane");
  datasetX.Address.AddAddressRow(p1, 1, "The Street");
  datasetX.Address.AddAddressRow(p2, 2, "The Road");

That should be all; launch the app and choose a person, the address should change automagically (John on the street, Jane on the road)